# How can I get the registered service with the gRPC service class or function instead of in the Main() function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, grpc

I have a gRPC service with several functions.

To make it simple

```
public GreeterService : GreeterServiceBase
{
    public override Task<SayHelloResponse> SayHello(SayHelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {...}
    public override Task<SayByeResponse> SayBye(SayByeRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {...}    
}
```

After I registered the dependency in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, IMyInterfaceImpl>();
    }
```

According to the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1,

I can get it back at Program.Main() through serviceScope.ServiceProvider

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var myDependency = services.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>();
                myDependency.WriteMessage("Call services from main");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

One point I am not quite sure is how can I get it at my gRPC service (GreeterService) or functions (SayHello() and SayBye()), it looks like that I cannot get the Services via ServerCallContext.

Any help is highly appreciated.